# NavigationActions.reset() in V1 vs StackActions.reset() in V2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Previously i was using react navigation V1 and `NavigationActions.reset()` was very useful when i needed to restrict going back to a particular screen. Now when i updated **react navigation to V2**  `NavigationActions.reset()` was removed and added to `StackActions.reset()`.

With V1 reset() i can reset back to screen that are out of stack but now with V2 reset i can only reset back to screen inside a stack.

Can you help me understand the difference and suggest a better solution for reset() in V1.

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be because in favor of SwitchNavigator